# How can i assign velocities?

Tags: vector-spaces

Note: Please forgive me for asking such a question. In my school they only covered very basic vector introduction and we arent set to study this kind of things for a long while.

My problem is that i am working on a online game server, (SA:MP).
The multiplayer itself gives very little control about data, so most of it has to be calculated ourselves.

Recently i got the idea of introducing bullet collisions (By default we have no way of knowing whether a bullet was fired or where it hit).
I can detect when a bullet was probably fired, depending on when a player loses a bullet. I can't however, detect where the bullet went.
Using some methods i was able to deduce where it probably landed, by simply calculating the maximum height of every coordinate in its way.

Using a function (Defined to return three numbers, each denoting one unit of the x,y,z direction of where the player is looking), coupled with the x,y,z coordinates of the player's camera it can be calculated where the bullet hit. Now i want to 'fly' the player to the coordinate.

For this i disable the gravity, but how do i set his velocity? (I have a function that allows me to set the velocity in the x,y,z direction, but what values do i pass to it?)

I highly appreciate the time you are taking to answer this question.

Note: Just for reference in case the info might be needed, the functions are detailed at http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/GetPlayerCameraFrontVector, http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/GetPlayerCameraPos and http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/SetPlayerVelocity

Comment: I think you just want http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/GetPlayerCameraFrontVector. Setting the player's velocity to the camera's axis vector will cause the player to move "in" to the camera.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! If possible, could you tell me how to calculate the time required for the player to reach the target? So that i can reenable gravity once hes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(t_x, t_y, t_z)$ is the position of the target, $(c_x, c_y, c_z)$ is the position of the camera, and $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ is the direction of the camera and velocity of the player. Then the player reaches the target at time

$$t=\frac{\left[(t_x,t_y,t_z)-(c_x,c_y,c_z)\right]\cdot(v_x,v_y,v_z)}{(v_x,v_y,v_z)\cdot (v_x,v_y,v_z)}.$$